Target file "flutter" not found
I'm encountering an issue with Flutter commands, receiving "Target file 'flutter' not found." Despite Flutter being installed correctly and the PATH set to /path/to/flutter/bin, the error persists. I've tried flutter upgrade, reinstalling Flutter, and checking file permissions, but nothing has worked. I'm running on [Your OS and version]. Any advice on resolving this?
Target file "flutter" not found.

did you  try with restating the computer

Post a screenshot of the project and where the error message is displaying.

What do you see when you run the command which flutter?
